# Request forwarding in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, request, forward

I have two files in my route folder of node application like fetchCity.js and addNewDevice.js.  I want to forward the request parameters from addNewDevice.js to fetchCity.js and process the response in addNewDevice.js file. I tried following code but is not working.

```
    var express = require('express');

    module.exports = function(app){
        var cors = require('cors');
        var coptions = {
            "origin": "*",
            "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,POST,OPTIONS",
            "preflightContinue": false,
            "allowedHeaders":['Content-Type']
        }
        var db = require('./dbclient');
        var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
        app.use(cors(coptions));
        app.use(bodyParser.json());
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
        app.post('/newBinDevice', function(req, res, next) {

            var did = req.body.deviceid;
            var sver = req.body.swver;
            var city = req.body.city;
            var circle = req.body.circle;
            app.post('/fetchCityArea',function(req,res){
                    console.log('Response from fetchCityArea is ' + JSON.stringify(res));
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by using http module in node.js code and sending the request as per below pseudo code.

```
var http = require('http');

app.post('/abc',function(req,res) {
        http.get(url,function(resp){ 
                resp.on('data',function(buf){//process buf here which is nothing but small chunk of response data});
                resp.on('end',function(){//when receiving of data completes});
        });     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
app.post('/fetchCityArea',function(req,res){
                    console.log('Response from fetchCityArea is ' + JSON.stringify(res));
            });
```

Use :

```
res.redirect('/fetchCityArea');
```

Reason : app.post('/someRoute') is a http listener module not a http request module. whereas res.redirect is a function of response object which will redirect the payload to the route passed to it.

Comment: I think it will redirect the user and response will be sent to the user. users can send requests to /fetchCityArea any time. But when they send request to /addNewDevice then the i need response of /fetchCityArea to be processed in /addNewDevice. If I am wrong pl correct me. Because I did not find how to get response object after using redirect method in the server code.

Comment: yes you are right. Are you doing the processing of the request also in the app.post handler itself?

Comment: Yes, i want to send the request to /fetchCityArea from /addNewDevice and upon receiving the response, i want to process it further in /addNewDevice. The expected behavior is similar to RequestDispatcher.forward method in Java.